Problem in using Context api and react router dom together
I was trying to use context api and react router dom together but facing an issue, cartItem  which is value passed to context provider is {} object in cart component item but working fine I mean getting modified as expected in Product component
This all is happening when I am using react router dom but when I am not using it, code is working fine and as expected.
App.js
import './App.css';
import { Product } from './components/product';
import   CartContextProvider from './context/cartcontext';

import { Cart } from './components/cart-component';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  // const [cartItem, setCartItem] = useState({});

  return (
    

      // <CartContextProvider>
      //   <Product />
      //   <Cart />
      //   </CartContextProvider>
      <Router>
      <CartContextProvider>  
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<Product />} />
          <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart />} />
        </Routes>
      </CartContextProvider>
    </Router>
     
   
  );
}

export default App;


Product component
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Product.scss';
import productobj from './productobj';
import  { useCartContext } from '../../context/cartcontext';

export default function Product() {


  const { cartItem, setCartItem } = useCartContext();
  console.log("context",useCartContext());

  // State to manage quantity for each product
  const [quantities, setQuantities] = useState(productobj.map(() => 1));

  // Function to handle increasing quantity for a specific product
  const increaseQuantity = (index) => {
    const newQuantities = [...quantities];
    newQuantities[index] += 1;
    setQuantities(newQuantities);
  };

  // Function to handle decreasing quantity for a specific product
  const decreaseQuantity = (index) => {
    if (quantities[index] > 1) {
      const newQuantities = [...quantities];
      newQuantities[index] -= 1;
      setQuantities(newQuantities);
    }
  };

  const handleAddToCart = (product, index) => {
    // Check if quantity is greater than 0 before adding to cart
    if (quantities[index] > 0) {
      let cartList = (prevCartItem => {
        const newCartList = { ...prevCartItem };

        // Use product ID as the key for cart items
        if (!newCartList[product.id]) {
          newCartList[product.id] = {
            id: product.id,
            name: product.name,
            price: product.price,
            quantity: 0
          };
        }

        newCartList[product.id].quantity += quantities[index];
        setQuantities(prevQuantities => {
          // Reset quantity to 1 after adding to cart
          const newQuantities = [...prevQuantities];
          newQuantities[index] = 1;
          return newQuantities;
        });
        //console.log("new cart list",newCartList);
        return newCartList;
      });
      setCartItem(cartList);
      console.log("new cart item",cartItem);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='products'>
      {productobj.map((product, index) => (
        <div key={index} className='main'>
          <h3 className='product-name'>Products with id = {product.id}</h3>
          <p>{product.name}</p>
          <p>{product.description}</p>
          <p>{product.price}</p>
          <div className='quantity-container'>
            <button onClick={() => decreaseQuantity(index)}>-</button>
            <input type='text' value={quantities[index]} readOnly />
            <button onClick={() => increaseQuantity(index)}>+</button>
          </div>
          <hr />
          <div className='product-footer'>
            <input type='submit' name='addtocart' value='Add To Cart' onClick={() => handleAddToCart(product, index)} />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}


context.js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

 const cartContext = createContext();

 function CartContextProvider({children}){
    const [cartItem, setCartItem] = useState({});
    

    return <cartContext.Provider value={{cartItem,setCartItem}}>
        {children}
    </cartContext.Provider>
    
}

export function useCartContext(){
    return useContext(cartContext);

}

export default CartContextProvider;

cart component
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './cart.scss';
import { useCartContext } from '../../context/cartcontext';

import useApiCall from '../../customHooks/ApiHook';

export default function Cart() {

  const [totalprice, setTotalPrice] = useState(0);

  const { cartItem , setCartItem} = useCartContext();
  console.log("context",useCartContext()); //showing empty 
  


  const cartKey = Object.keys(cartItem);


  const accesskey = 'jgt_lh5w-iQJz57Fmn6j0AW_n08PHx6xi96pk8iNhaA'; // Corrected access key

  const { isLoading, data, apiError } = useApiCall(null, "GET", 'https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random', accesskey);

  // Log data if there's no API error
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!apiError && data?.urls?.raw) {
      console.log("data url",data.urls.raw);
    }
  }, [data, apiError]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTotalPrice(cartKey.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      return acc + cartItem[cur].price * cartItem[cur].quantity;
    }, 0)); // Initialize with 0
  }, [cartKey, cartItem]);

  let imageUrl = data && data.urls && data.urls.raw ? data.urls.raw : "";

  const handleRemoveItem = (itemId) => {
    const newCartItem = { ...cartItem };
    delete newCartItem[itemId];
    setCartItem(newCartItem);
  };

  const handlePlaceOrder = () => {
    // Implement logic to place order
    
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2 className='cartheading'>My Cart</h2>
      <div className="cart">

        {isLoading ? (
          <p>I am Loading</p>
        ) : (
          <div className="product-item">
            {cartKey.length > 0 ? (
              cartKey.map((item) => (
                <div className="product-display" key={item}>
                  <div className='product-image'>
                    {apiError ? (
                      <p>I am not available= {apiError}</p>
                    ) : (
                      <img src={imageUrl} alt="product" height={200} width={200} />
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <div className='product-details'>
                    <p>Product Id : {cartItem[item].id}</p>
                    <p>Product Name :{cartItem[item].name}</p>
                    <p>Product Price : {cartItem[item].price}</p>
                    <p>Product Quantity : {cartItem[item].quantity}</p>
                  </div>
                  <button onClick={() => handleRemoveItem(cartItem[item].id)}>Remove</button>
                </div>
              ))
            ) : (
              <div>
                <p>No Item Found, Please add items in the cart</p>
              </div>
            )}
            <button className='placeorder' onClick={handlePlaceOrder}>Place Order</button>
          </div>
        )}
        <div className="cart-math">
          {/* I will show here total price and total quantity */}

          <div className='math-main'>
            <div className='price-heading'>
              Price Details:
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div className='price-summary'>
              <p>Price:</p>
              <p>Discount: </p>
              <p>Delivery Charges:</p>

            </div>
            <hr />
            {/* how to give dotted line */}
            <div className='price-total'>
              <strong>Total Price: {totalprice}</strong>
            </div>
            <hr />
            {/* how to give dotted line */}
            <div className='price-message'>
              <p>You will save $ in this order</p>
            </div>
            <hr />
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}



I don't see any overt issue(s) in the code. Are you manually updating the URL from "/" to "/cart" and reloading the page, e.g. the cart state is re-initialized? Please [edit] to include your exact reproduction steps.

Exactly re intialization is happening, when I have given some default object it working fine with default value, which make me stand in side that re initialization is happening when I am manually handling the URL . Now my question is what would be the solution for this scenario. Do I have to go to localstorage or what?
But storing value in localstorage would vanish the fundamental of context API

No, the React Context API exists to solve the problem of props drilling, e.g. drilling props from the component with the state through all the components between it and any components that actually care about that state. You'd have the same problem state resetting when reloading the page even with local state and no context. Yes, persisting the state to localStorage is a common solution. Do you need help specifically with this issue?

I have one more question on top of it, how is context is getting maintained while state is change which cause re- render and how it is different from manually changing the URL

Updating React state only triggers a component rerender... it doesn't reload the entire page and remount everything. Updating the URL makes the browser request the page from the server and reloads the page... anything that was running is torn down and the new page request is loaded. You can use the Link component or navigate function to issue client-side navigation actions to other "pages" your app is rendering. React-Router allows your Single-Page-App to simulate being a Mult-Page-App.

Thank you this made me understand things in much better way that manually changing the URL invlove reloading which indeed making context reset

Great, happy to help. I'm voting to close this post as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers!
